# Second Screen resolution not availailable

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I am trying to set the resolution for my secondary screens.

I have a ThinkPad laptop with two additional monitors. The laptop an the left monitor show 1920x1080 resolution, while on the second monitor this resolution isn't available.

I have tried with `xrandr` add resolution commands but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)). Thanks.

Comment: It got solved. Tnx.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please consider to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) Thanks.